# Send form data to a pdfkit iframe document

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, pdfkit

I would like to retrieve the values of a form and send them to a pdfkit document generated in back end.

For the moment, I only have created a simple document by a "get" route :

```
router.get(
  "/",
  authCheck,
  asyncHandler(async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    let filename = "toto";
    filename = encodeURIComponent(filename) + ".pdf";
    res.setHeader(
      "Content-disposition",
      'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
    );
    res.setHeader("Content-type", "application/pdf");
    const content = "contenu";
    doc.y = 300;
    doc.text(content, 50, 50);
    doc.pipe(res);
    doc.end();
  })
);
```

Here is the code to retrieve the created document :

```
<iframe className="preview-pdf__container" src={pdfContent} />
```

How do I send my form data and get it back into the document? With a POST?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to get data from my form into my server then export it to different files with in my server using node.js if it helps. I am not entirely sure on how to get it back out of your server into an iframe though.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <form action="/login" method="POST">
            <label id="email-label">Email</label>
            <div class="textarea" id="email">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="authentactor-email" value="" required>
            </div>

            <label>Password</label>
            <div class="textarea" id="password">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="authentactor-password" value="" required>
            </div>

            <div id="button-wrapper">
                <button type="submit" id="button">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

node.js

```
 //Allows you to Export form data from index.js
 app.post('/login');
```